# Why does win32com.shell does not list my iphone when invoking through pywebview?

Tags: python, windows, shell

I want to use win32com to transfer photos from my iphone to my
computer (I found a code snippet here, that worked for me:
https://gitlab.com/lassi.niemisto/iphone-photo-dump/).
In addition I would like to use pywebview to build a GUI.

Behaviour of the shell listing the resource "My computer" is
unexpected when I access the win32com functions through pywebview as
it is not showing my iphone then.

Here is a minimal working example (you may have to replace the String
== "Dieser PC" according to the language of your windows):

```
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
from webview import create_window, start, windows

class Api():
    def listFoldersDieserPC(self):

        folder = shell.SHGetDesktopFolder()
        for item in folder:
            print("loop: ", folder.GetDisplayNameOf(item,
shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL))
            if folder.GetDisplayNameOf(item, shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL) ==
"Dieser PC":
                new_folder = folder.BindToObject(item, None,
shell.IID_IShellFolder)
                break

        # list folders in Dieser PC/This Computer
        for item in new_folder:
            print("loop: ", new_folder.GetDisplayNameOf(item,
shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL))


api = Api()
window = create_window('Test', 'index.html', js_api=api, min_size=(600, 450))
api.listFoldersDieserPC()
print("now from the browser")
start()
```

With index.html:

```
<button value="asdf"
onClick="window.pywebview.api.listFoldersDieserPC()">List
Folders</button>
```

The first time I call the function api.listFoldersDieserPC directly
from python, the second time through the button in the pywebview
browser window.

This is the output:

```
loop: Dieser PC
loop: Downloads
loop: Bilder
loop: Musik
loop: Desktop
loop: Dokumente
loop: Videos
loop: Apple iPhone
loop: Local Disk (C:)

now from the browser

loop: Dieser PC
loop: Downloads
loop: Bilder
loop: Musik
loop: Desktop
loop: Dokumente
loop: Videos
loop: Local Disk (C:)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It is the same, except that the folder for Apple iPhone is missing on
the second go.

Why is the shell behaving differently here? Is this a bug in win32com
or is pywebview influencing it somehow? What can I do to make it work?

Kind regards

Comment: The only thing I can think of that might cause this is that maybe the webview has lower permissions than the main thread and so it isn't allowed to see that specific folder when it tries to get it from the web view. Either that or it could be a problem with one of the libraries as I don't really see any other potential causes.

Comment: Sounds sane. is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: It wouldn't be ideal but it's possible that if you used the button to run a separate script then it might inherit the permissions of the user and not the web viewer which would mean it should produce the correct output. There is probably a better way to fix this but unfortunately I think this would require more knowledge of the libraries than I have, so this is all I can really come up with.